# Is JSON an alternative to XML?

Tags: xml, json

I think there must be some significant difference between XML and JSON .. I referred these two links (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21817156/alternative-to-xml-and-json) and  these links ([JSON alternatives (for the purpose of specifying configuration)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813727/json-alternatives-for-the-purpose-of-specifying-configuration)) gave me some ideas . This question is asked by my interviewer and he said that your assumptions were wrong. And he didn't told me the actual answer .  Really is there any significant difference .

Comment: You will probably find [this](https://www.udemy.com/blog/json-vs-xml/) article helpful.

Comment: The biggest difference is that JSON is designed for data, XML is designed for documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In My view it isn't . Each has its own pros and cons

Answer (score 1):

No way,both have their own features and one is suitable over the other depending on the place where they will be used.

See this answer, it will clear your doubt hopefully.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4862530/2035885

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536893/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-xml-and-json